# Ubuntu 16.04 not recognizing LG 4G phone

Tags: usb, phone

I used to be able to plug my phone in to my USB and seamlessly move files back and forth. Now the phone does not show up at all in the menu bar or in my file system when plugged in. From the phone's end, it still gives a "Allow this computer to access your phone data?" prompt which I allow. Is there a way to reinstall this function?

Comment: Check your notification center. Is there something that says something like "USB connected: charging"? If there is, tap it and choose the "File Transfer" or "MTP" option.

Comment: There are no notifications. This seems to be connected to a problem I was having with gvsfd-smb-browser eating up all of my cpu last night. In an attempt to fix, I deleted gvsfd-smb-browser (which seemed to do nothing to fix the problem) and also did the following: sudo chmod 744 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb-browse

Comment: You should try to revert that if you can.

Comment: I realize, but don't know how. I tried purging Samba and reinstalling, but it gives me a system error. I suspect that is due to the changes in privileges I made, but don't know exactly which privilege I should change it back to.

Comment: I can try checking

Comment: My 16.04 machine says `-rwxr-xr-x` for that file, but I think you should be worried about MTP, not SMB, since that's what the USB connection uses. Try a different cable.

Comment: Forgive me, but I basically just copy/paste commands and don't know exactly how to type them - could you provide this example for me? Right now, I really need to get Samba back on and working I think.

Comment: I would look up how to purge and reinstall Samba. That would be the best way.

Comment: I've done that. I've purged it and reinstalled it 3 times, all ending with system errors. I believe the issue may be that change in privilege /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb-browse but I don't know how to change the privilege back to the way it was.

Comment: Did you purge Samba? Because that should remove any file needed for Samba. Ask another question and please post the errors you get in that question.

Comment: I did purge Samba, yes. But I have figured it out and fixed it - had to reinstall gvfs backends in addition to purging/reinstalling samba. Thanks for your effort help and I think (hope) I've learned my lesson in this...

Comment: Hopefully :p. So does the file transfer work now or is that still an issue?

Comment: Yep, working perfectly now.